# how to write a csv file in another csv file in python without pandas

Tags: python, csv

I am a beginner in python, I want to read a csv file and create a second csv file with with some of the data from the first csv.I did this but the second file have only the header

```py
def create_fifa(infile, outfile):
   
    fieldnames = ["Team", "Nationality", "Position", "Age", "Potential" ,"Name"]
    writer = csv.DictWriter(outfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    data = csv.writer(outfile)
    writer.writeheader()
    for row in csv.DictReader(infile):
        writer.writerow(row)
        data.writerow((row))
    return outfile
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume `fieldnames` is a subset of all the columns.  In that case, you need to use `extrasaction='ignore'`.

An example with an NBA dataset as I don't have your FIFA dataset.

```
import csv

infile = 'C:\\Users\\BRB\\nba.csv'
outfile = 'C:\\Users\\BRB\\NewFile.csv'

keepList = ['Name','Team','Position','Age','Height','Weight']

def create_nba(infile, outfile, fields):

    infile = csv.DictReader(open(infile))
    writer = csv.DictWriter(open(outfile,'w'), fieldnames=fields, extrasaction='ignore')
    writer.writeheader()

    for row in infile:
        writer.writerow(row)

    return outfile


f = create_nba(infile, outfile, keepList)
```